# SAS and XML: XML element name is too long for a SAS variable name

Tags: xml, sas

I try used that code:

```
libname phuse xml 'T:\XX\XX\XX\XX\XX\file_name.xml' xmlmeta=schemadata;
data work.study_abc; 
    set phuse.study_abc;    
run;
```

But source file has too long variable name and SAS occured:

```
ERROR: The XML element name <SomeFieldInXMLfileWhereIsTooLong> is too long for a SAS variable name.
ERROR: Encountered during XMLMap parsing at or near line 891, column 53.
```

Exist method where I can rename field during import XML file in 'set'?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML documents such as renaming nodes. You can call XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 scripts with SAS's `proc xsl`, then import the transformed XML file. Specifically, use the identity transform with a separate template to rename top level node of *any* node located *anywhere* in the document.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ADJUST match VALUE AND <shortername> NODES -->
  <xsl:template match="SomeFieldInXMLfileWhereIsTooLong">
    <shortername>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </shortername>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**SAS**

```
proc xsl 
    in="C:\Path\To\Input.xml"
    out="C:\Path\To\Output.xml"
    xsl="C:\Path\To\XSLT_Script.xsl";
run;

libname phuse xml 'C:\Path\To\Output.xml' xmlmeta=schemadata;

data work.study_abc; 
    set phuse.study_abc;    
run;
```

---

To demonstrate, below XML includes the current top five StackOverflow [SAS users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sas/info) with very long nested node name that is transformed with XSLT and its output imported into SAS.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stackoverflow>
    <topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>
      <user>Joe</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/1623007/joe</link>
      <year_rep>1,005</year_rep>
      <total_rep>56,363</total_rep>
      <tag1>sas</tag1>
      <tag2>sas-macro</tag2>
      <tag3>sql</tag3>
    </topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>
    <topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>
      <user>Tom</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/4965549/tom</link>
      <year_rep>6,378</year_rep>
      <total_rep>28,990</total_rep>
      <tag1>sas</tag1>
      <tag2>sas-macro</tag2>
      <tag3>sql</tag3>
    </topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>
    <topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>
      <user>Reeza</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919583/reeza</link>
      <year_rep>1,507</year_rep>
      <total_rep>14,671</total_rep>
      <tag1>sas</tag1>
      <tag2>sas-macro</tag2>
      <tag3>sql</tag3>
    </topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>
    <topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>
      <user>DomPazz</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/2734437/dompazz</link>
      <year_rep>85</year_rep>
      <total_rep>12,001</total_rep>
      <tag1>sas</tag1>
      <tag2>sas-macro</tag2>
      <tag3>sql</tag3>
    </topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>
    <topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>
      <user>Richard</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249962/richard</link>
      <year_rep>5,075</year_rep>
      <total_rep>13,519</total_rep>
      <tag1>sas</tag1>
      <tag2>sas-macro</tag2>
      <tag3>proc-sql</tag3>
    </topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019>    
</stackoverflow>
```

**XSLT**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="topsasonstackoverflowusersoverallyear2019">
    <top_sas_users>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </top_sas_users>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**SAS**

```
proc xsl 
    in="C:\Path\To\Input.xml"
    out="C:\Path\To\Output.xml"
    xsl="C:\Path\To\XSLT_Script.xsl";
run;

libname mydata xml 'C:\Path\To\Output.xml' xmlmeta=schemadata;

data xml_data; 
    retain user link year_rep total_rep tag1 tag2 tag3; 
    set mydata.top_sas_users;       
run;

proc print data=xml_data; run;
```

[image: SAS data set output]